# How can i send a list from Background service to activity in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

i want to send a list from Background service to activity in android

```
public class MyService extends Service{

    private String receiverUserInfoId;
    private String loginUserInfoId;
    private String orgMsgThreadId;
    private String userName = "Vipin";
    DatabaseHelper db;
    MessageListActivity ms;
    private String userAvatarURL;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
        loginUserInfoId = extra.getString("LoginUserInfoId");
        receiverUserInfoId=extra.getString("UserInfoId");
        orgMsgThreadId = extra.getString("OrgMessageThreadId");
        userName=extra.getString("UserName");
        userAvatarURL=extra.getString("UserAvatarURL");


        new syncMessageFromServer().execute();
        new SyncPendingMessageToServer();


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
private class syncMessageFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // setting progress bar to zero
            //progressBar.setProgress(0);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return uploadFile();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private String uploadFile() {
            String str = "";
            HttpResponse response;
            HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/AndroidApp/GetMessage?loginUserInfoId=" + loginUserInfoId + "&recieverUserInfoId=" + receiverUserInfoId + "&isPendingToSynce=" + true);

            try {
                response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
                for (int i = 0; i <= jArray.length() - 1; i++) {
                    JSONObject row = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    ChatMessage cm = new ChatMessage();

                    cm.setOriginalMsgThreadId(row.getString("MessageThreadId"));
                    cm.setSenderUserInfoId(row.getString("SenderUserId"));
                    cm.setReceiverUserInfoId(row.getString("MultipleReceiversId"));
                    cm.setMessageStatus("SENT");
                    cm.setIsPending(0);
                    cm.setMessageText(row.getString("MessageText"));
                    cm.setMediaURL(offlineFileURL);
                    cm.setThumbImage(offlineFileURL);
                    cm.setMediaMIMEType("");
                    cm.setMediaSize(0);
                    cm.setMediaName("");
                    cm.setLatitude("");
                    cm.setLongitude("");
                    cm.setSendTimeStamp(row.getString("SendTime"));
                    cm.setReceiveTimeStamp(row.getString("ReadTime"));
                    long messageThreadId = db.SendMessage(cm);

                  MessageListActivity mLA = new MessageListActivity();
                  mLA.SetListData(cm);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return str;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new syncMessageFromServer().execute();

        }
    }
}
```

i want to send ChatMessage to the SetListData() function in MessageListActivity class how can i do this. just i want to refresh my list adapter to new message fetched by the server

Comment: You could use Otto for this aswell. It's used to pass around messages without having to keep listener references. This means you don't have to worry about activity recreation. you can find the documentation and set-up here: https://github.com/square/otto

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a messenger if you want to communicate with the activity. Change your service like this:

```
public class MyService extends Service{
    public static int MESSENGER = 1;
    public static int JSONARRAY = 2;
    private String receiverUserInfoId;
    private String loginUserInfoId;
    private String orgMsgThreadId;
    private String userName = "Vipin";
    DatabaseHelper db;
    MessageListActivity ms;
    private String userAvatarURL;
    Messenger messageActivity;
    final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

    class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what){
             case MESSENGER:
                  messageActivity = msg.replyTo;
                  break;
        }
    }    

    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
        loginUserInfoId = extra.getString("LoginUserInfoId");
        receiverUserInfoId=extra.getString("UserInfoId");
        orgMsgThreadId = extra.getString("OrgMessageThreadId");
        userName=extra.getString("UserName");
        userAvatarURL=extra.getString("UserAvatarURL");


        new syncMessageFromServer().execute();
        new SyncPendingMessageToServer();


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
private class syncMessageFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // setting progress bar to zero
            //progressBar.setProgress(0);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return uploadFile();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private String uploadFile() {
            String str = "";
            HttpResponse response;
            HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/AndroidApp/GetMessage?loginUserInfoId=" + loginUserInfoId + "&recieverUserInfoId=" + receiverUserInfoId + "&isPendingToSynce=" + true);

            try {
                response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
                messageActivity.send(Message.obtain(null, JSONARRAY, jArray.toString()));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return str;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new syncMessageFromServer().execute();

        }
    }
}
```

And in your activity add the following methods:

```
public class MyListActivity extends Activity{
     public static Messenger mService = null;
     public final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
     public boolean mIsBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_participant);
        doBindService();
    }

public void doBindService() {
        if (!mIsBound) {
            context.bindService(new Intent(context,
                    MyService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            mIsBound = true;
        }
    }

         private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            mService = new Messenger(service);

            try {
                Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MyService.MESSENGER);
                msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
                mService.send(msg);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mService = null;

        }
    };

class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MyService.JSONARRAY:
                    buildTheChatMessage((JsonArray)msg.obj);

                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public void buildTheChatMessage(JsonArray arr){
           ChatMessage cm = new ChatMessage();

                    cm.setOriginalMsgThreadId(row.getString("MessageThreadId"));
                    cm.setSenderUserInfoId(row.getString("SenderUserId"));
                    cm.setReceiverUserInfoId(row.getString("MultipleReceiversId"));
                    cm.setMessageStatus("SENT");
                    cm.setIsPending(0);
                    cm.setMessageText(row.getString("MessageText"));
                    cm.setMediaURL(offlineFileURL);
                    cm.setThumbImage(offlineFileURL);
                    cm.setMediaMIMEType("");
                    cm.setMediaSize(0);
                    cm.setMediaName("");
                    cm.setLatitude("");
                    cm.setLongitude("");
                    cm.setSendTimeStamp(row.getString("SendTime"));
                    cm.setReceiveTimeStamp(row.getString("ReadTime"));
                    setListData(cm);
    }


}
```

This way your activity is bound to the service and you can communicate between them. I wish you get the idea from this code and implement what you need.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)'s a source to read more about this methods.